# Scraping from multiple url's using beatifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have my code working. Now I would like to do a little bit of modification to get the date from multiple URLs, But URLs have only one word difference.

Here is my code, I am fetching from only one URL.

```
from string import punctuation, whitespace
import urllib2
import datetime
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import csv
today = datetime.date.today()
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid").read()

soup = Soup(html)
print "INSERT INTO `property` (`date`,`Url`,`Rooms`,`place`,`PId`,`Phonenumber1`,`Phonenumber2`,`Phonenumber3`,`Typeofperson`,` Nameofperson`,`typeofproperty`,`Sq.Ft`,`PerSq.Ft`,`AdDate`,`AdYear`)"
print 'VALUES'
re_digit = re.compile('(\d+)')
properties = soup.findAll('a', title=re.compile('Bedroom'))

for eachproperty in soup.findAll('div', {'class':'sT'}):
  a      = eachproperty.find('a', title=re.compile('Bedroom'))
  pdate  = eachproperty.find('i', {'class':'pdate'})
  pdates = re.sub('(\s{2,})', ' ', pdate.text)
  div    = eachproperty.find('div', {'class': 'sT_disc grey'})
  try:
    project = div.find('span').find('b').text.strip()
  except:
    project = 'NULL'        
  area = re.findall(re_digit, div.find('i', {'class': 'blk'}).text.strip())
  print ' ('
  print today,","+ (a['href'] if a else '`NULL`')+",", (a.string if a else 'NULL, NULL')+ "," +",".join(re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", (a['onclick'] if a else 'NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL')))+","+ ", ".join([project] + area),","+pdates+""
  print ' ), '
```

Here are the URLs that I would like to fetch from, at the same time

```
http://www.99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid
http://www.99acres.com/property-in-thoraipakkam-chennai-south-ffid
http://www.99acres.com/property-in-madipakkam-chennai-south-ffid
```

So you can see that there is only one word that differs in every URL.

I am trying to create an array like the following

```
for locality in areas (http://www.99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid
, http://www.99acres.com/property-in-thoraipakkam-chennai-south-ffid,    http://www.99acres.com/property-in-madipakkam-chennai-south-ffid):
link = "str(locality)"
html = urllib2.urlopen(link)
soup = Soup(html)
```

This quite does not seem to work and I actually would like to just pass that ONE WORD to the URL like this

```
for locality in areas(madipakkam, thoraipakkam, velachery):
    link = “http://www.99acres.com/property-in-+ str(locality)+-chennai-south-ffid"
    html= urllib2.urlopen(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Hope I made it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
for locality in areas (http://www.99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid, http://www.99acres.com/property-in-thoraipakkam-chennai-south-ffid,    http://www.99acres.com/property-in-madipakkam-chennai-south-ffid):
link = "str(locality)"
```

… is not going to work, for multiple reasons.

First, you're calling an `areas` function you never defined anywhere. And I'm not sure what you expected that function to do anyway.

Second, you're trying to pass `http://www.99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid` as if it were a meaningful Python expression, when it's not even parseable. If you want to pass a string, you have to put it in quotes.

Third, `"str(locality)"` is the literal string `str(locality)`. If you want to call the `str` function on the `locality` variable, don't put quotes around it. But really, there's no reason to call `str` at all; `locality` is *already* a string.

Finally, you didn't indent the body of the `for` loop. You have to indent that `link =` line, and all the stuff you were previously doing at the top level, so that it falls under the `for`. That way, it happens once for each value within the loop, instead of just once total after all the loops are done.

Try this:

```
for link in ("http://www.99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid",
             "http://www.99acres.com/property-in-thoraipakkam-chennai-south-ffid",
             "http://www.99acres.com/property-in-madipakkam-chennai-south-ffid"):
    # all the stuff you do for each URL
```

---

You were on the right track with this:

```
for locality in areas(madipakkam, thoraipakkam, velachery):
link = “http://www.99acres.com/property-in-+ str(locality)+-chennai-south-ffid"
```

Using a "template string" to avoid repeating yourself is almost always a good idea.

But again, there are a number of problems.

First, you've again called an `areas` function that doesn't exist, and tried to use bare strings without quotes around them.

Second, you've got the opposite problem to the last one: you tried to put expressions that you want to evaluate, `+` and `str(locality)`, into the middle of a string. You need to break this up into two separate strings that can be part of the `+` expression.

And again, you haven't indented the loop body, and you're calling `str` unnecessarily.

So:

```
for locality in "velachery", "thoraipakkam", "madipakkam":
    link = “http://www.99acres.com/property-in-" + locality + "-chennai-south-ffid"
    # all the stuff you do for each URL
```

---

While we're at it, it's usually a lot easier to read your code, and easier to make sure you haven't gotten something wrong, when you use formatting functions instead of trying to concatenate strings together. For example:

```
for locality in "velachery", "thoraipakkam", "madipakkam":
    link = "http://www.99acres.com/property-in-{}-chennai-south-ffid".format(locality)
    # all the stuff you do for each URL
```

Here, it's immediately obvious where each locality will fit into the string, and what the string will look like, and where the hyphens are, and so on.

Comment: Let me try this. And what If I wanna save the result in separate file for each locality.?

Comment: @Venky: If you want to save the result to a separate file, do the same trick you used for the URL to get a filename, e.g., `filename = "spam-{}-eggs.html".format(locality)`. Then open and write using that filename: `with open(filename, 'w') as f: f.write(whatever)`. And make sure you do it inside the `for` loop, of course. That's about all there is to it.